# How do I rename part of the filename in multiple files?

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have numerous files in a directory with a variety of names that have one pattern in common—the file names end with _rgb.jpg. I'm looking for a simple command that will change that name ending to _cmyk.jpg on multiple files in that directory. I would prefer to do this in the command line.

Comment: `rename` command in `util-linux` package.

Comment: Search the site. It already has many answers, most tagged with [batch-rename]. In a pinch you can do this with already installed tools by `find`ing the files, using `basename` and `mv`. And with extra tools as an option (such as the one mentioned by Ipor) it gets even easier.

Comment: Sorry. I don't want to install software. Can I do it in Bash?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick script I made.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *_rgb.jpg
do
   echo mv ${file} ${file%_rgb.jpg}_cmyk.jpg
done
```

If you're happy with the results remove the `echo`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. That should get all files in that directory with a single simple command.

```
rename 's/_rgb.jpg/_cmyk.jpg/' *
```